# GraphicsItem paint Image with some transparent parts

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to transparent image by mouse event. I try rectangle on the image, but it fills with color black with Xor_mode and remain red rectangle with DestinationIn_mode.

My goal is to erase some pixels by mouse then blends multiple images together.

Someone can help me?

[image: img]

with the code below I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om2rc.png)
,but why BLACK but not the transparent background with striped lines?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF, Qt, QPoint, QPointF, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QBrush, QPixmap, QPainter, QImage, QPainterPath, QColor, QBitmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QFrame, QGraphicsPixmapItem, \
    QGraphicsItem, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent, QGraphicsRectItem


class CutImg(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, qPixmap):
        super(CutImg, self).__init__()
        self.qPixmap = qPixmap

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(self.qPixmap.rect())

    def paint(self, qPainter, qStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget=None):
        qPainter.drawPixmap(QPointF(), self.qPixmap)
        qPainter.setCompositionMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_Xor)
        qPainter.fillRect(QRectF(QPointF(30, 50), QPointF(100, 150)), QBrush(Qt.red))



class CutScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CutScene, self).__init__()
        self.cuttedImg = None

    def setPixmap(self, qPixmap):
        self.mainImg = CutImg(qPixmap)
        self.addItem(self.mainImg)
        self.cuttedImg = qPixmap


class MainCutWindow(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainCutWindow, self).__init__()
        self.scene = CutScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.boardmargin = 100

    def setPixmap(self, qPixmap):
        self.scene = CutScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setFixedSize(qPixmap.width() + self.boardmargin * 2, qPixmap.height() + self.boardmargin * 2)
        self.scene.setPixmap(qPixmap)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainCutWindow()
    window.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/cat.jpg'))
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I don't understand you, could you explain me better. You can also provide the .jpg

Comment: the goal I want to do is like the first image, draw somethings by mouse and transparent the image, as "erase" the image, but I get the black color instead, how to fix it?